# Split table vs. same values in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table `products`:

```
#products
ID | category | type | criteria1 | criteria2
```

, with `category` and `type` being foreign keys of other tables.

Should I split this table up into `category1_type1_products`, `category1_type2_products` and so on? It seems to me I should, because right now in my table, there are some thousands of entries with the same `ID` and `category` value. Loads of redundand information.

Also, a query could perform faster if mysql didn't have to search for all rows with the specific category and type first. (right?)

Is this recommended structuring behaviour at all? If not, what if my table has got 5 million tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That would mean the table NAME contains DATA - you then have to modify the database structure (create new table) just to add one more category or type.

If your category/type column is tinyint or smallint (depending on reasonably expected number of possible values), then you actually have proper normalization in place. If there is no (functional) dependence between two keys to categories for two different rows then those two values are not a redundancy but a minimal way to store the actual data.

From performance standpoint the important part is proper indexing for your queries. If you often search for rows with specific category and/or type, you should have in place index on that column (or composite index on both columns, and possibly other) to optimize such queries. You should enable the slow query log and periodically check what queries are taking most time (you may use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the log) and optimizing those (adding proper indexes and/or rewriting the queries).

When you have proper indexes in place then in your proposed case of multiple tables actually selecting the right table to read will take about the same time as MySQL needs to "jump" to the right part of the index. (It is a bit oversimplification but the point is that selecting the right table to read is an overhead in itself).

From the "schema" standpoint I would be more concerned about those two columns `criteria1` and `criteria2` if these are their real names and usage then that seems like a possible problem - but that may depend on your use case and may be actually OK. But if there is any chance you will once add `criteria3` and others then that would tell you to add separate table for those, one row per criteria and FK to the current table.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was 110% helpful to me! I actually plan to add `criteria` dynamically from time to time. However, I don't quite understand why I should put them in an extra table. I still need them as columns in the current table anyway..? still this wasnt even part of the question, so thanks again

Comment: If you need multiple columns like these and they are of the same type, then you just remove them from this table and create a different table with one column of the needed type and one column as FK to the current table (each "criterion" knows which product it belongs to). Then you might want to add either for instance some auto_increment column to work as a primary key OR an "order" column containing a number telling if "criteria1" or "criteria2" etc is stored in that row. You then have multiple rows in that table for each product (row) in the original table.  ...

Comment: ... You can query them separately (`select ... from product_criteria where product_id IN (<products you are interested in>)` or by joinin the proper "order" criterion to the product row (if you know which one or some constant number of them you really want). If you try to join then to your "original" product query, it will repeat the product row multiple times and adding one of the associated criteria to each one - multiplying the number of returned rows - that may be used in some cases but is a bit cumbersome to pull of in others.

Comment: this took me a while to understand, but I'll try it out. cheers and good night

Comment: no, I don't get it. I obviously need these criteria columns as... columns. Every product should be able to have a value for each criteria, as you said, with a junction table. But if I want to get a table which includes some products *and* their respective criteria data, I need to have `criterion1`,`criterion2` and so on as **columns**. But by using a `JOIN`, the criteria IDs will come out as **rows**, right to the `product` table. I probably misunderstand something here

Comment: should I make a new question out of this?

Comment: I will try to answer here.. If you want to get a product with all its criteria, there are multiple ways to do it - either a direct join (multiple rows with repeated product info for each row of criteria), do a query for product and then another one to get all criteria and build the "table" with more columns dynamicaly in your app code, or use `GROUP_CONCAT` if you really need to do it in sql. It all depends on how you want to use the results - what for do you need the *"table which includes some products and their respective criteria data"*

Comment: 4 years later, I will now continue this project. I now agree with you, when the amount of "columns" (in OP, `criteria1`, `criteria2` etc) varies, they should reside in a seperate table. Regarding your question, what for: The use case is retrieving filtered, sorted data. A sample pseudo query might be `select id, criteria1, criteria5 from products where criteria4 > 15`...

Comment: ... As the table will be primarily read-intensive and big, those queries need to be performant. As such, joining the `criteria` and `product_criteria` data tables for each query beforehand would be too slow. I am currently considering a separate caching table for quick access, or maybe a view. Still need to read into this as I am unfamiliar with common SQL caching strategies